# How to rollback unit test while service layer is @Transactional

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-transactions, spring-test

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.2.RELEASE and my service classes is annotated with

```
@Service
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
```

My unit test class is annotated with:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
```

I wish to roll back changes made in the database by unit test methods after test is finished.

**One of the proposed solutions** is to add `@Transactional` annotation over the test class, I tried it but this solution produces some issues, is that sometimes the test transaction is rolled back (even without no exceptions thrown!) before the service transaction is completed.

Is there another good solution to rollback test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution with the `@Transactional` on the test class is the standard way of doing this. There is no way Spring Tx would roll back a transaction out of the blue, so I'd recommend looking closer into the issues that you encountered instead of inventing other solutions.

Comment: maybe this is the best suggestion so far, i will dig deeper in my test method to see what maybe causing this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

all changes will be rollbacked if didn't change default behaviour. And you don't have classes / methods with transaction propagation level = REQUIRES_NEW  as it start independent transaction and can commit or rollback independently with the outer transaction

> Transaction rollback and commit behavior
>
> By default, test transactions will be automatically rolled back after
>   completion of the test; however, transactional commit and rollback
>   behavior can be configured declaratively via the @Commit and @Rollback
>   annotations.
>
> @Rollback
>
> @Rollback indicates whether the transaction for a transactional test
>   method should be rolled back after the test method has completed. If
>   true, the transaction is rolled back; otherwise, the transaction is
>   committed (see also @Commit). Rollback semantics for integration tests
>   in the Spring TestContext Framework default to true even if @Rollback
>   is not explicitly declared.
>
> When declared as a class-level annotation, @Rollback defines the
>   default rollback semantics for all test methods within the test class
>   hierarchy. When declared as a method-level annotation, @Rollback
>   defines rollback semantics for the specific test method, potentially
>   overriding class-level @Rollback or @Commit semantics.

Comment: Weird, i am not using propagation new and the default behavior is no rollback, what do you recommend ?

Comment: 1) I wrote - 'And you don't have'.  2) even if call is success transaction in  rollback after test is finished. It's default behavior  for test. If you need save changed and do not do rollback use @Rollback(false) in test class or method

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#testcontext-tx-rollback-and-commit-behavior):

> By default, test transactions will be automatically rolled back after
>   completion of the test; however, transactional commit and rollback behavior can be configured declaratively via the @Commit and @Rollback annotations.

Your comment:

> sometimes the test transaction is rolled back (even without no
>   exceptions thrown !) before the service transaction is completed !

doesn't make sense to me. How did you know whether the txn completed or not if it was rolled back? Exceptions don't matter for tests, as I quoted the doc above.

Comment: in the console i see the log: rolled back transaction, and this is logged sometimes (not always) before some methods is invoked inside my unit test method.

Comment: @MahmoudS Is the test data left in the DB after the test completion or not?

Comment: when i use transacional in test class the test data is not left but as i said sometimes the test gets rolled back for no reason and skips invoking some methods !

Comment: "skips invoking some methods" has nothing to do with rollback. Your problem statement is wrong.

Comment: no no i was very clear that i need another solution than using transactional annotation on test class because it skips invoking some methods sometimes !!!!